# In Fancybox 2.0 (using NextGen Gallery), the elastic option makes images appear from center of screen, not image origin

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

In Fancybox 2.0 (using NextGen Gallery), the elastic option makes images appear from center of screen, not image origin

I would it to appear to come from the image position like in the example. I've coppied the exact code from the example, but didn't get the desired results

website:
http://www.beerpong.kevindaniels.net/competitive-beer-pong/wsobp-archive/wsobp-7/

**EDIT** : My code (moved from comment)

```
jQuery('.fancybox').fancybox({
    openEffect: 'elastic',
    openSpeed: 150,
    closeEffect: 'elastic',
    closeSpeed: 150,
    prevEffect: 'none',
    nextEffect: 'none',
    closeBtn: false,
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        },
        buttons: {}
    },
    afterLoad: function () {
        this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
    }
}).removeAttr("title");
```

Comment: My code:
    jQuery('.fancybox').fancybox({
        openEffect : 'elastic',
    openSpeed  : 150,
    closeEffect : 'elastic',
    closeSpeed  : 150,

    prevEffect : 'none',
    nextEffect : 'none',

    closeBtn  : false,

    helpers : {
     title : {
      type : 'inside'
     },
     buttons : {}
    },

    afterLoad : function() {
     this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
    }
       }).removeAttr("title");

Answer (score 1):

Add this option: `'orig': $(this)`

It sets the origin of the effect to the element being clicked.